# How to move files between document libraries with their references?

Tags: document-library

I have a blog in my SharePoint site and I forgot to create a well structured hierarchy to drop my files I link into my posts (Word documents, PDF, JPG screenshots,...). Now the blog as been running for a month and I realise I need a library hierarchy to be able to manage the amount of files.

How can I move these files to the new Document Library and also move the reference to these files in my posts? I really do not want to do that manually!

Comment: Are these files already in a Document Library or Site Assets Library? Are you using SharePoint Publishing Pages for your blog?

Comment: Yes it is a Document Library in a publishing website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write short PowerSell script, which will grab your blog pages content and replace old links to new. I did this few times, it is not enough, but [here some basic comandlets](http://milingon.com/blog/2011/powershell-crib.aspx) to work with SharePoint. Blog post content is field, you can change it programmatically by script and replace links like this:

```
$web = Get-SPWeb http://web
$list = $web.Lists["Posts"]
$item = $list.Items[0]
$content = $item["Content"]
$item["Content"] = $content.Replace("http://oldlink", "http://newlink")
$item.Update()
```

You can do this in the loop and using diferent masks, if you have not complete correspondance of old and new links. User PowerShell ISE - it's IDE for development scripts to create more complex scripts.